# Header is not showing in react-navigation-drawer React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am implementing `react-navigation-drawer` from React Navigation Library. But facing problem related to header. The header bar is not showing in any of the screens.

This is my `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View } from "react-native";
//import DrawerNavigator from "./navigation/DrawerNavigator";
import { Platform, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Contact from "./components/contact";

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const RouteConfigs = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  Contact: {
    screen: Contact
  }
};
const DrawerNavigatorConfig = {
  drawerWidth: WIDTH * 0.75,
  drawerType: "both",
  initialRouteName: "Home"
};
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  RouteConfigs,
  DrawerNavigatorConfig
);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MyApp />;
  }
}
```

And this is my `home screen`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Image, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome";
import { faTruck, faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: "Home",
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <FontAwesomeIcon size={25} icon={faHome} />
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24
  }
});

export default Home;
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The drawer navigator does not contain headers. Stack navigators must be configured to display headers.

```js
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  RouteConfigs,
  DrawerNavigatorConfig
);

const Root = createStackNavigator({
  Main: { screen : DrawerNavigator}
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions : ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "Screen"
    })
})

const Stacks = createAppContainer(Root)

export default Stacks;
```

[image: screen]

Comment: it is working, but with static header title `screen`. How can I do it dynamic ? Also I want to include a menu icon and some other icons in the header bar.

Comment: @AlokMali Please refer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html

Comment: do you know the solution for react navigation 5?

Comment: @JimmySorza It doesn't differ from the previous way.

Comment: @hongdeveloper it is different, I will show you a solution that I found.

Answer (score 12):

@hongdeveloper this is a simple example solution for react navigation 5:

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen options={{title: "Profile"}} name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen options={{title: "Settings"}} name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can find about the navigation to a screen in a nested navigator in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) and [you can try this example on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Nesting%20navigators%20%C2%B7%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%405.0.4%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fnest-navigators.js)

Comment: Perfect. Thank bro.

Answer (score 8):

Since December 2020 you can now use the `headerShown: true` setting in `screenOptions` of your Drawer.Navigator to show the header in React Navigation 5.

See more about this issue here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1632

See the commit and comments about the new feature in React Navigation 5 here

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/dbe961ba5bb243e8da4d889c3c7dd6ed1de287c4

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, But I did it with the below code.

I created separate stack navigators for each screen and after that added all the stack navigators in the drawer navigator.

The good thing is it is fully customized.

Please see my code below.

```
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: Home
    },
    {
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1e89f4'
          },
          headerTitle: 'Knowledge Woledge',
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            flex: 1
          },
          headerLeft: (
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 13 }}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                size={25}
                color='#fff'
                icon={faBars}
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              />
            </View>
          ),
          headerRight: <View />
        };
      }
    }
  );

  const DetailNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      PostDetail: PostDetail
    },
    {
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1e89f4'
          },
          headerTitle: () => {
            return (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: '#fff',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  flex: 1,
                  fontSize: 20
                }}
              >
                {navigation.getParam('headerTitle')}
              </Text>
            );
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            flex: 1
          },
          headerLeft: (
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 13 }}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                size={25}
                color='#fff'
                icon={faArrowLeft}
                onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}
              />
            </View>
          ),
          headerRight: <View />
        };
      }
    }
  );
```

Assigned this in a const

```
const RouteConfigs = {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Home',
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesomeIcon size={20} color={tintColor} icon={faHome} />
        )
      }
    },
    Detail: {
      screen: DetailNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

And finally, create a drawer navigator with this.

```
const DrawerNavigatorConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH * 0.75,
    drawerType: 'both',
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  };
  const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    RouteConfigs,
    DrawerNavigatorConfig
  );

  const Stacks = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

  export default Stacks;
```